# Grails domain class, String field TEXT and LONGTEXT

Tags: grails

In a Grails domain class, how do I set the constraint for a String field so that its MySQL column type is  TEXT or LONGTEXT?

So far my best approach is to set the constraint's size:

```
myTextField(size:0..65535)
```

which results in TEXT

```
myTextField(size:0..2147483646)
```

results in LONGTEXT (2147483646 = 2^32 / 2 - 1 - 1)

Is there a cleaner way to specify the size? Basically I want the full range of TEXT or LONGTEXT without having to hardcode a bunch of size values.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can declare that in the mapping closure of your Domain class:

```
static mapping = {
   myTextField type: 'text'
}
```

(See [ORM DSL Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#ormdsl))

Comment: FYI in case anyone else has the same issue, the type must be specified as lowercase, if it is uppercase it fails.

Answer (score 5):

using sqlType would allow you to go for finer grained constraint

```
Class Foo{
    String myTxtAsVarchar
    String myTxtAsText
    String myTxtAsLtext

    static mapping = {
       myTxtAsVarchar  sqlType: 'varchar(255)'
       myTxtAsText     sqlType: 'text'
       myTxtAsLtext    sqlType: 'longText' 
    }
    /*applying constraint on DB end + on Domain model(scaffolding/Validation)*/
    static constraints = {
           myTxtAsVarchar  size: 2..255
           myTxtAsText     size: 2..15000
     }
}
```

using SQL type also made available actual Blob type (byte type linked to tinyBlob by default)

more mapping detailed here: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html